# oracle not accepting output from the user and throwing error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi i was trying to create a simple sum function which takes input from the user and displays the output but whenever i run the code it is throwing the errors which i absolutely don't know what they are. can anyone please help regarding this matter.

the code for the program is:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
a number;
b number;
s number;
begin
a:= &a;
b:= &b;
s:=a+b;
dbms_output.put_line('sum: '||s);
end;
/
```

the error encountered are:

```
Error at line 1/5: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 847
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 833
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1903


1. set serveroutput on
2. declare
3. a number;
```

Comment: `set` is a client command, not part of SQL (or PL/SQL). You can't call it from Apex.

Answer (score 0):

That's Apex' "SQL Command", and you can't use substitution variables there.

As you said:

> i was trying to create a simple sum **function**

then do so - create a function (write `create function` and press Ctrl + Enter to actually create it; then call it using the `select` statement by *selecting* it (mark the whole line with a mouse) and execute it the same way. See the result at the bottom of the screenshot):

[image]

---

On the other hand, if it were SQL*Plus, then your code would work:

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2  a number;
  3  b number;
  4  s number;
  5  begin
  6  a:= &a;
  7  b:= &b;
  8  s:=a+b;
  9  dbms_output.put_line('sum: '||s);
 10  end;
 11  /
Enter value for a: 1
Enter value for b: 3
sum: 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: nope i am getting a error even when i am literally copy pasting your code for the sqlplus part. @Littlefoot

Comment: Here is the error:

ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "&" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>

   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>

   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev

   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval

   date <a string literal with character set specification>

   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe

   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specifi

Comment: You can't use SQL*Plus code in Apex, Mohd. Use a function instead.